# How to add Custom Attributes in Google shopping content api with php?

Tags: php, magento, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I am using google shopping Api from last one year it is working properly. But now I want to add new attributes in it such as `CustomLabel5`. For that I have used `setCustomAttributes()` method and passed three attributes `name`, `type` ,`value`.
**But it is working showing error 400 invalid attribute values**. following is my code please check and suggest proper answer for that.

```
$product = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product();
$data= new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductCustomAttribute();
$data->setName('CustomLabel5');
$data->setType('text');
$data->setValue('test');
$product->setCustomAttributes($data);
```

Please give answer.

Comment: Please tell the correct way to do it

Comment: I am also facing same problem if any one have correct answer then please reply.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple fix here.

`setCustomAttributes` expects an array of `Google_Service_ShoppingContent_ProductCustomAttribute` instances.

What you need is:

```
$attributesArray = array($data);
$product->setCustomAttributes($attributesArray);
```